# cannot set renderer on openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

According to a book I am reading about Openlayers 3 , all I have to do, to reset the renderer is to do this in the `Map` initialization

`renderer: 'dom'`

so my code is

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [layer],
    renderer: 'dom',
    view: view,     
});
```

When I load the page, the console gives no errors, but the map does not load at all. I use Openlayers 3.9.0. What is going wrong here?

Thanks

EDIT

This is all the openlayers code

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var kbz = new ol.interaction.KeyboardZoom();
    var dr = new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom();


    var control = new ol.control.FullScreen();
    var center = ol.proj.transform([-1.812, 52.443], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');



    var we = new ol.Overlay({
        position: center,
        element: document.getElementById('we')
    });


    var view = new ol.View({
        center: center,
        zoom: 6
    });


   var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [layer],
      renderer: 'dom',
      view: view        
   });

    map.addInteraction(kbz);
    map.addInteraction(dr);
    map.addControl(control);


    map.addOverlay(we);
```

Comment: Something related to your layer. Show some more code.

Comment: @JonatasWalker I just added more code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the size of the map target element, when using the `dom` renderer.

Canvas elements, which are used by the default renderer, has a default height of *150px*, while normal `div`s don't have a default height. Setting the height of the target should make you map appear:

```
#map {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: @slevin here it is. How about this change?

Comment: @Alvin Lindstam OK, my `css` now is  `#map {
 height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #b5d0d0;
}`Now I see the map, but when I click `inspect element` on the map I still see `<canvas class....`. Same goes if I remove the `background-color` and both width and height are in pixels